# Static variable and memory allocation in class and its use

Tags: c++, static, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new with c++ and I don't completely understand the concept of static variables.
I have a static variable in a class.

```
class FCCommunication : public OEMThread
{
public:
    FCCommunication();
    static bool MASTER;
}
```

I am initializing my code and allocation memory to the `FCCommunication` in the source file using following two statements

```
FCCommunication * FCObject = 0;

FCObject = new FCCommunication();
```

now the question for me is that what will happen if I try to access MASTER variable before the object and memory allocation will be done like this

```
if(FCCommunication::MASTER)// this gets called before dynamic memory allocation.
{
//do something here.
}
```

Comment: Many beginners books and tutorials describes `static` member variables as *class member variables*. That is because they belong to the *class* and not any specific instance of the class. That's the reason you need to define the static member variables separately. And that in turn means you can use static member variable (or static member functions) before you create any instances.

Comment: so if I call it like this FCObject->MASTER instead of FCCommunications::MASTER what will be the difference? will it disrrupt my OS? Consider the same case of allocation.

Comment: Nothing you do on a modern system using a protected mode operating system should affect the OS. And using a specific instance to access a static member is unusual but not invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static member variables are allocated as any other non-member variable with *static storage duration*. Meaning that they end up in a chunk of data initialized before the program is started, most often called either `.bss` or `.data`, depending on if the initalizer is a zero value or not.

So the static member variable is not actually allocated together with the class and the value you initialize it to is set by code executing before the rest of the class is even allocated.

This means that you can actually access static members no matter if any instance of the class exists or not. You can think of them as "global variables with restricted access and scope", because that is exactly what they are.

Meaning that your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful. Now one more doubt what if the instance is not there and a variable non static? what would happen? Am i inviting a memory leak in the case?

Comment: @SPandya Not sure what you mean. If it wasn't static you wouldn't be able to access it through `FCCommunication::`.

Comment: I meant by using of the class object. Like  FCObject->MASTER, but the instance hasnt been encountered.

Comment: @SPandya That's not valid C++, it is what the `::` is for.

Comment: True, :: is for static but what about non static variable?

Answer (score 0):

C++ member static variables (of a class) belong to all instance of that class, and they are initialized before any instances of that class are initialized. So, you can use both FCCommunications::MASTER and FCObject->MASTER to access those static variables with no differences.

One thing you should be careful about is that you have to define those static variable separately. That say, you have to do something like this, outsides the class definition:

```
bool FCCommunications::MASTER = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

static members are members initialied to zero for first time it is initialized...
IN otherr words , they belongs to a common pool.
any other object can access it.
scope is within the class
the lifetime is the lifetime of the program.